# Response Code 800, LdapReferralException when querying Active Directory with Apache JMeter

Tags: apache-http-server, jmeter

When using JMeter to query our AD, we get a response code 800, with an LdapReferralException as shown in the image. Note that the response contains the user data that we searched for. However, it appears this response code (800) being non-zero causes JMeter to flag an error or failure. Consequently, that step of JMeter test fails.

[image: Error message shown in JMeter View Results]

Update:
Note that the issue was that I was using Xpath Assertions. As suggested by @Dmitri T, once I switched to use Response Assertion (with text comparisons), I can select the "Ignore Status" checkbox and things work alright.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If JMeter does what it is supposed to be doing and you just want the sampler to be marked as passed - try adding [Response Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) as a child of the request and tick `Ignore Status` box - it should suppress JMeter operation status check and the result will be marked as successful.

[image]

You can also specify additional success criteria there, i.e. check for anticipated data in response. See [Response Assertions in JMeter 3.2 - New and Improved](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/response-assertions-in-jmeter-32-new-and-improved) article for more information on conditionally marking JMeter sample results as successful or failed.

You might also want to check [*jmeter.log* file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/hints_and_tips.html#debug_logging) - in case of failure the associated [Exception](https://stackify.com/specify-handle-exceptions-java/) should be printed there.

Comment: Yes, that helped @Dmitri T.  We were stuck in the world of performing an XPath Assertion. However simply using a "Response Assertion" with text and with "ignore status" helped us. Thank you,